# access DropdownContent on hover with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

My main project is to change dropdown content depending of the date and time of day perhaps. Right now I am trying to change the dropdown content as i click the button.
Here is what I have:

```
current block: 
<div id="dropdown">
   <span>1</span> 
   <div class="dropdown-content">
      <p>1</p>
      <p>2</p>
      <p>3</p>
      <p>lunch</p>
      <p>4</p>
      <p>5</p>
   </div>
   <div class="dropdown-content2">
      <p>1</p>
      <p>2</p>
      <p>3</p>
      <p>pack</p>
      <p>lunch</p>
      <p>4</p>
      <p>5</p>
   </div>
   <div class="dropdown-content3">
      <p>1</p>
      <p>2</p>
      <p>3</p>
      <p>lunch</p>
      <p>4</p>
      <p>5</p>
      <p>Event</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#dropdown {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content3 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
#dropdown:hover .dropdown-content2 {
    display: none;
}
#dropdown:hover .dropdown-content3 {
    display: none;
}
```

And JS:

```
function SwapDivsWithClick()
{
   var d1 = document.getElementById('dropdown:hover .dropdown-content');
   var d2 = document.getElementById('dropdown:hover .dropdown-content2');
   var d3 = document.getElementById('dropdown:hover .dropdown-content3');
   d1.style.display = "none";
   d2.style.display = "none";
   d3.style.display = "block";
```

I am trying to access #dropdown:hover .dropdown-content in Javascript. But I don't understand how.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean you are `trying to access #dropdown:hover .dropdown-content`, what do you mean by "access"? you want the contents of the element? you want the element itself?

Comment: document.getElementById needs a html id as a parameter. When you get an element by getElementById, then you can bind some action to the hover event

Comment: FYI: you can use getElementsByClassName or getElementsByTagName, but hovering is an event, so you must bind this event listener to desired elements

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your current output vs. expected output? What button are you clicking? `dropdown:hover` is a css property... you wouldn't access it. It is the css property that is applied to `dropdown` on hover. You would just look for `dropdown` - the html element you are trying to access

Comment: And why you are trying to do in the javascript the thing you already did in css?

Comment: Would i be better to make content show up on hover using JS rather than CSS? If so, how could I do that?

Comment: I just want to change the dropdown content as i click a button. (sample button i have:  <button onclick="SwapDivsWithClick()">Click Me</button>